# I am trying to 'nest' xsl:for-each (I think)

Tags: xml, xslt, html-table

Very simply I am trying to do a list of item by another item - I have tried to make it simple by only having 2 levels a Band Name and their CDs

I am trying a number of different avenues - but cant get the xsl to break the xml into separate columns in a table.

Its actually for a property website and is supposed to show the rentals achieved for certain properties - but to make it easy the use of bands and their cd's seems simpler....

My XML

```
<catalog>
  <artist>
    <name>Band 1</name>
    <titles>
      <title>CD Title 1</title>
      <title>CD Title 2</title>
      <title>CD Title 3</title>
      <title>CD Title 4</title>
      <title>CD Title 5</title>
      <title>CD Title 6</title>
      <title>CD Title 7</title>
    </titles>
  </artist>
  <artist>
    <name>Band 2</name>
    <titles>
      <title>CD Title 10</title>
      <title>CD Title 20</title>
      <title>CD Title 30</title>
    </titles>
  </artist>
  <artist>
    <name>Band 3</name>
    <titles>
      <title>CD Title 100</title>
      <title>CD Title 200</title>
      <title>CD Title 300</title>
      <title>CD Title 400</title>
      <title>CD Title 500</title>
      <title>CD Title 600</title>
      <title>CD Title 700</title>
      <title>CD Title 800</title>
    </titles>
  </artist>
</catalog>
```

My XSL

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#ff3366">
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Title</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/artist">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>

          <td><xsl:value-of select="titles"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
```

What I want!!

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Artist</th>
    <th>Title</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Band 1</td>
    <td>CD Title 1</td>
    <tr><td></td><td>CD Title 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>CD Title 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>CD Title 4</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>CD Title 6</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>CD Title 7</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>CD Title 8</td></tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Band 2</td>
    <td>CD Title 10</td>
    <tr><td></td><td>CD Title 20</td></tr>
    <<tr><td></td><td>CD Title 30</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>CD Title 40</td></tr>
    <<tr><td></td><td>CD Title 50</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>CD Title 60</td></tr>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Band 3</td>
    <<td>CD Title 100</td>
    <tr><td></td><td>CD Title 200</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>CD Title 300</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td>CD Title 400</td></tr>
  </tr>
</table>


What I get

<html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#ff3366">
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Title</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Band 1</td>
        <td>CD Title 1CD Title 2CD Title 3CD Title 4CD Title 5CD Title 6CD Title 7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Band 2</td>
        <td>CD Title 10CD Title 20CD Title 30</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Band 3</td>
        <td>CD Title 100CD Title 200CD Title 300CD Title 400CD Title 500CD Title 600CD Title 700CD Title 800</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want? Multiple rows nested inside a row? Anyway, you only need to add another `xsl:for-each` instruction: `<xsl:for-each select="titles/title">`.

Comment: You're clearly new to XSLT so the first thing to check is which version of XSLT you are using; many people are still using the 20-year-old XSLT 1.0, but later versions (2.0 and 3.0) are much more powerful. In questions on this forum you should tag the question with the appropriate XSLT version, because it will often affect the answer.

Comment: Thanks guys - yes I am new to xslt - As far as version is concerned it says "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>" at the top of the xsl - copied from W3 - should this change to xml version="2.0" ?

Comment: @Cranberry To use XSLT 2.0, you need a XSLT 2.0 **processor**.  Changing the stylesheet will do you no good if your processor does not support XSLT 2.0 features.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your desired HTML outcome is correct, because your first `title` would make an unusual exception.

So the following XSLT-1.0 code will create the (hopefully) desired outcome. I also changed the organization of the stylesheet from `for-each` loops to templates.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <html>
    <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#ff3366">
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Title</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="artist" />
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artist">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="titles/title" />
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title[1]">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Its outcome is:**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#ff3366">
            <th>Artist</th>
            <th>Title</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Band 1</td>
            <td>CD Title 1</td>
            <tr>
               <td>CD Title 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>CD Title 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>CD Title 4</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>CD Title 5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>CD Title 6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>CD Title 7</td>
            </tr>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Band 2</td>
            <td>CD Title 10</td>
            <tr>
               <td>CD Title 20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>CD Title 30</td>
            </tr>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Band 3</td>
            <td>CD Title 100</td>
            <tr>
               <td>CD Title 200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>CD Title 300</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>CD Title 400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>CD Title 500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>CD Title 600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>CD Title 700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>CD Title 800</td>
            </tr>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this but its not quite right.

What I need is:

      BAND              TITLE
      Band 1              CD Title 1
                               CD Title 2
                               CD Title 3

      Band 2              CD Title 10
                               CD Title 20

      Band 3              CD Title 100
                               CD Title 200
                               CD Title 300

etc etc..
Maybe its not possible??

Comment: @Cranberry: I improved my answer. Now its output matches your desired outcome.

Comment: Much better thanks!!  I will try and get the additional column myself!!

Comment: follow on - how do i check my xsl xslt version - I'm hosting on GoDaddy?

Comment: If you do not know, it's probably version 1.0. My answer also is of version 1.0, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I finally came up with after all you guys help!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/catalog">
    <html>
    <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#ff3366">
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Title</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="artist" />
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artist">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="titles/title" />
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title[1]">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```